# Spring boot jpa hibernate HQL query with group by gives Validation failed for query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, hql

In spring boot app I have an ElementEntity:

```
....
@Entity
public class ElementEntity
{
    @Id
    int id;
    Double quantity;
    String form;
    String color;
    String type;
    String description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "form")
    private FormEntity form;
}
```

And I have here FormEntity:

```
 @Entity
 public class FormEntity {
       .....
      @OneToMany
      @JoinColumn(name = "links")
      private List<LinksEntity> links;
    }
```

I want using HQL to  generate a query that will sum the values of quantity field, group by **color** and and to return an list of  `[{qty, color, links}]`
I did this HQL query:

```
@Repository
public interface ElementRepository extends JpaRepository ... {


@Query("SELECT sum(quantity) as qty, color, form.links  FROM ElementEntity" +
        "WHERE type= ?1" +
        "GROUP BY color")
List<Object[]> findAllBy ElementAndGroup(String type);
```

This gives  `Validation failed for query for method public abstract findAllByElementAndGroup` and it happens because of `form.links`which is a  `@OneToMany` relation.

How can I fix this query so I group the data by color and return the form links?

Comment: @AlanHay I updated the question, can you check please

Answer (score 0):

*Updated after question update*

You can use `join` in your query.  Don't forget to add the columns to `group by`:

```
@Query("SELECT sum(e.quantity) as qty, f.color, l.id  FROM ElementEntity e " +
        " join e.form f" + 
        " join f.links l " + 
        " WHERE e.type= ?1 " +
        " GROUP BY e.color, l.id")
```

In the code above I assumed that name of id field in FormEntity is `id`. Change `form.id` if the assumption isn't right.

Updates after discussion:

```java
@Query("select sum(e.quantity), f  FROM ElementEntity e join e.form f where e.type = ?1  group by f ")
List<Object[]>findAllByElementAndGroup(String type);
```

```java
final List<Object[]> aggregatedData = elementRepository.findAllByElementAndGroup("some type");
for (Object[] o : aggregatedData) {
     final Number quantitySum = (Number) o[0];
     final FormEntity form = (FormEntity) o[1];
}
```

Comment: I updated the question, the problem i have is not adding the form.id is adding other fields inside form, which in this case is links whuch is a `list` of LinksEntity, how can I add it in this case, because I tried to add it on the group by but it gives the same error

Comment: Now I get `hql could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]` and from `private List<LinksEntity> links;`  accessing by `private FormEntity form;` I want to get everything not just id

Comment: 'get everything not just id' - just remove `.id` and leave `l`. It will return you whole `LinkEntity`.

Comment: `could not extract ResultSet` - impossible to understand what is the problem. Not enough information.

Comment: I fixed that, now I get duplicates rows. For example if I have 1 element row  with  1 form  and it has 20 links.  Instead of getting ` 1 row  eg  element id, list<links> `  I get `20 rows with element id and link fields` how can I return the `@OneToMany` to return a list per row instead of rows ? @petr-aleksandrov

Comment: You can update the query to return Form: `SELECT sum(e.quantity), f  FROM ...`. Then you will be able to get the list of Links from the Form using getter: `FormEntity#getLinks`

Comment: can you give an example please, I couldn't make it work

Comment: I've added example to the answer.

Comment: I see. I tried it but I get error `Column 'form.description' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. ` And I get this for all the fields on it. I tried to add them on the group but it doesn't make sense to add everything